# Error while installing terraform provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on creating an EKS cluster I am using the eks module that is provided in the terraform registry.

When trying to initialize`terraform init` I am getting the below error

```
Error: Failed to install provider
```

`│ │ Error while installing terraform-aws-modules/http v2.4.1: archive has incorrect checksum │ zh:455f4c979e5a658172fa6350b260c9748663dcdb948a92169f36ac41a4e16a87 (expected │ zh:9a235610066e0f7e567e69c23a53327271a6fc568b06bf152d8fe6594749ed2b)`

below is the module code.

````
```module "eks" {
````

```
cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
cluster_version = "1.20"
subnets         = module.vpc.private_subnets

tags = {
  Environment = "training"
  GithubRepo  = "terraform-aws-eks"
  GithubOrg   = "terraform-aws-modules"
}

vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

workers_group_defaults = {
  root_volume_type = "gp2"
}

worker_groups = [
  {
    name                          = "worker-group-1"
    instance_type                 = "t2.small"
    additional_userdata           = "echo foo bar"
    asg_desired_capacity          = 2
    additional_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.worker_group_mgmt_one.id]
  },
  {
    name                          = "worker-group-2"
    instance_type                 = "t2.medium"
    additional_userdata           = "echo foo bar"
    additional_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.worker_group_mgmt_two.id]
    asg_desired_capacity          = 1
  },
]
}
```

Could someone please help on this.

I am currently using 1.0.8 terraform version and I am unable to find way to fix the issue

Could someone please help on this.